# Diffraction through a single slit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, diffraction

I'm having some trouble finding the answer to this homework question:

> A wide beam of light from a laser with a wavelength of 450.0 nm is
>   incident on a long narrow opening that is 0.300 mm wide. What will be
>   the width, in mm, of the central maximum on a screen 2.00 m from the
>   opening (i.e what will be the distance between the nodes adjacent to
>   the central maximum?) (Use the small angle approximation.)

So far I've attempted two solution from the formulas that I know, but I'm not getting the right answer. Both of my solutions are shown below. Is there something that I'm missing, either conceptually or mathematically?

**Given,**

$ \lambda = 4.5^{-4} mm$

$ a= 0.300 mm$

$ L= 2000 mm$

Find, $w = ?$

---

**Solution #1:**

$a = \frac{\lambda L}{w}$

$w = \frac{\lambda L}{a}$

$w = \frac{4.5^{-4} \times 2000 mm }{0.300 mm}$

$w = 3.00 mm$

---

**Solution #2:**

$\theta = \frac{2.44 \lambda}{a}$

$\theta = 0.00366 rad$

$\theta = \frac{w}{L}$

$w = \theta \times L$

$w = 7.32$

Answer (score 1):

In your solution #2, the formula $\theta = 2.44\lambda/a$ would hold for a circular slit with radius $a$. But if the slit is long and narrow, it is a rectangle; and diffraction on a rectangle is not given by a Bessel function but by a sinc function, see, e.g., [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction#Single-slit_diffraction). The constant will therefore not be 2.44 but something else, connected to the first zero of the sinc function.

Comment: I'm not understanding what a sinc function is... I think it may be beyond my level. The only other constant I can think of using is 1.22, but that didn't work either... is there any other suggestion you can give me?

Comment: @Vanessa The sinc function is explained shortly in the Wikipedia article; basically, $\mathrm{sinc}(x) = \sin(\pi x)/(\pi x)$.